# Best way to get list of tags by parent in Joomla 3.3?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, tagging

What is the best way (in j!3.3) of querying the db to generate a list of tags matching a particular parent and display on the front end (as a link with tag title and id)?

This is for a custom joomla mvc component which uses two joomla tag fields: "categories" and "collection". There is no documentation on this that I can see.

Comment: Well first of all this is simply the tags view with the compact layout in the front end which you can create with a menu item specifying all of those (and more). But do you mean in a module or something?

Comment: I am using the tags in a custom component to load items that share a category tag or collection tag. I don't want to load content articles, just change the dbo for the component's list view by adding a filter that corresponds with the tag.

Comment: Are you loading a list of items or a list of tags?